# How can I properly configure rails 3 nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

I have 2 models. Member and Survey

member.rb as follows

```
Class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :survey, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :survey

  attr_accessible :fname,:lname, :address, :city, :state, :zip, :email, :phone, :phone_alt, :e_contact, :e_contact_phone, :physician, :physician_phone, :chiropractor, :chiropractor_phone, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :survey_attributes

end
```

survey.rb as follows

```
Class Survey < ActiveRecord::base
  belongs_to :member
end
```

however, whenever I try to create the member with the survey attributes I receive

> ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: surveys

I am testing this via the console.

Comment: Did you try posting actual form?

Comment: maybe it is :surveys_attributes in attr_accessible ?

Comment: Yes, the actual form produces the same output and removing surveys_attributes does not change the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a `has_one` association the accessible call should read:

```
attr_accessible :survey_attributes
```

The params you're posting need to be nested, like so:

```
params = { :member => { :name => 'Jack', :survey_attributes => { :attribute => 'value' } } }
```

In the form make sure that you're building the nested relationship correctly, ie. you must use:

```
= form_for @member do |f|
  ...
  = f.fields_for :survey do |s|
    ...
```

If you have those things setup like so it should work. If this isn't catching your error then please show a log of what you're trying in the console and isn't working.

See [#accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) in the Rails API for more info.

Comment: My form was generating an incorrect attribute for survey (surveys). Updated the form to survey_attributes and all is well. Thanks!